# Spawn askdirectory from a button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I need to add a button that the user presses to launch a Tkinter.askdirectory, and be able to capture the result. I have tried many examples, but could not find anything that works successfully in my particular case (the case where I am new at this and don't really know what I am doing :)

I have commented out what I have done, so that the original code still works, and so you can sort of see what I have been trying. Which is mostly not working as I am in unfamiliar territory with Tk. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

class Values(Tkinter.Tk):
    """docstring for Values"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        stepOne = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text=" Create A Playlist ")
        stepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
#         self.getAdir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=stepOne, title='Please select a directory')


        self.Val1Lbl = Tkinter.Label(stepOne,text="Playlist Name")
        self.Val1Lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='E', padx=10, pady=2)   
        self.Val1Txt = Tkinter.Entry(stepOne)
        self.Val1Txt.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, pady=2, sticky='WE')

        self.Val2Lbl = Tkinter.Label(stepOne,text="Task")
        self.Val2Lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='E', padx=10, pady=2)
        self.Val2Var = StringVar()    
        self.Val2Txt = Tkinter.OptionMenu(stepOne, self.Val2Var, 'Layout','Anim Pass 1','Anim Pass 2', 'Lighting', 'Compositing')
        self.Val2Txt.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4, pady=2, sticky='WE')

        self.Val3Lbl = Tkinter.Label(stepOne,text="Description")
        self.Val3Lbl.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='E', padx=10, pady=2)  
        self.Val3Txt = Tkinter.Entry(stepOne)
        self.Val3Txt.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=4, pady=2, sticky='WE')

#         self.Val4Lbl = Tkinter.Label(stepOne,text="Directory")
#         self.Val4Lbl.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='E', padx=10, pady=2)
#         self.Val4Var = StringVar()
#         self.Val4Var = Tkinter.Button(command=getAdir)
#         self.Val4Txt.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=4, pady=2, sticky='WE')


        self.val1 = None
        self.val2 = None
        self.val3 = None
#         self.val4 = None

        SubmitBtn = Tkinter.Button(stepOne, text="Submit",command=self.submit)
        SubmitBtn.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

    def submit(self):
        self.val1=self.Val1Txt.get()
        if self.val1=="":
            Win2=Tkinter.Tk()
            Win2.withdraw()

        self.val2=self.Val2Var.get()
        if self.val2=="":
            Win2=Tkinter.Tk()
            Win2.withdraw()

        self.val3=self.Val3Txt.get()
        if self.val3=="":
            Win3=Tkinter.Tk()
            Win3.withdraw()

#         self.val4=self.Val4Var.get()
#         if self.val4=="":
#             Win4=Tkinter.Tk()
#             Win4.withdraw()


    self.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Values(None)
    app.title('Bulk Movie Upload')
    app.mainloop() #this will run until it closes
    #Print the stuff you want.
    print app.val1,app.val2,app.val3 #,app.val4
```

Here is the revised code, from what I think you meant, but still has the errors in that it is not passing the variable out. I have edited this post, and the code, to simplify.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import Tkinter
    from Tkinter import *
    import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

    class Values(Tkinter.Tk):
        """docstring for Values"""
        def __init__(self, parent):
            Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.initialize()

        def getAdir(self):
            self.val5 = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=self, title='Please select a directory')



        def initialize(self):
            self.grid()
            stepOne = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text=" Create A Playlist ")
            stepOne.grid(row=1, columnspan=8, sticky='W',padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

            self.Val5Lbl = Tkinter.Label(stepOne,text="Select Folder Containing Movies")
            self.Val5Lbl.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)
            self.Val5Var = StringVar()    
            self.Val5Txt = Tkinter.Button(stepOne, text="Select Files", command=self.getAdir)
            self.Val5Txt.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=4, pady=2, sticky='WE')

            self.val5 = None

            SubmitBtn = Tkinter.Button(stepOne, text="Submit",command=self.submit)
            SubmitBtn.grid(row=6, column=3, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        def submit(self):
            self.val5=self.Val5Var.get()
            if self.val5=="":
                Win2=Tkinter.Tk()
                Win2.withdraw()


        self.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Values(None)
    app.title('Bulk Movie Upload')
    app.mainloop() #this will run until it closes
    #Print the stuff you want.
    print "Folder is - " + app.val5
```

Comment: You wrote "... from what I think you meant...". Who is "you"? If you have three or four answers to your question, how are we to understand what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big problem is that you are creating more than one instance of `Tk`. You can't do that. If you need more windows, create instances if `Toplevel`.

To call a function to ask for a directory, you need to create a function, and tie that function to a button. What you were doing was actually calling the function before you create the other widgets, rather than wait for the button press.

```
def getAdir(self):
   self.val4 = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=stepOne, title='Please select a directory')

...
self.Val4Var = Tkinter.Button(self, command=self.getAdir)
```

**Note: after I wrote the above, the question was changed to include different code. Here are my comments on that code:**

In the revised code, you're not doing what I suggested in my answer. You need to remove this line of code:

```
self.val5=self.Val5Var.get()
```

That is because `self.val5` already contains the directory returned from `askdirectory`. It will be a string, not some sort of object with a `get` method.

You also continue to have the problem that you're opening more than one root window. That will cause additional problems.

Comment: So is this where I am trying to create another instance of Tk.   "self.getAdir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=stepOne, title='Please select a directory')" ... ?

Comment: @user1978912: no, it's when you do this: `Win2=Tkinter.Tk()`. I didn't see where you were doing that, my apologies. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have implemented as I think you have suggested. But I am getting an error related to getAdir, and stepOne not being defined.

Comment: Where does the def in your answer go? ... I had it second from the top of the class, but I was getting "stepOne not defined" errors. So I tried to get it inside the "def initialize(self):" but have failed.

Comment: @user1978912: it goes wherever you want, as long as it's part of the class definition.